# How to extract data between square bracket [ ], but there are two square brackets [ ]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
    #Today: I have a pair [sneakers] in [blue]
```

As per the data above, how should i extract the keywords **blue** in the 2nd square bracket ? I try to use formula below, but it only extracts the words in the first [ ] sneakers instead of blue.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"\[(.*?)\]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formula:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(B2, "\][^\[\]]*\[", ","), "\[(.*)\]"), ","),,2)
```

Formula above replaces instances of `]<any non square bracket>[` to `,` then use the result and fetch the string inside the square bracket `[sneakers,blue,test]` then split using `,` and get the nth column.

To see how the formula works, separate it into 4 parts (per function).

[image]

Change last parameter to what order you want to get.

#### UPDATE:

```
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\][^\[\]]*\[[^""].*""([^""].*)""[^\""].*"),
 INDEX(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(B2, "\][^\[\]]*\[", ","), "\[(.*)\]"), ","),,2))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: hey thank you so much. it works like a charm!! I could never be like you, this is genius.

Comment: Hi there, thank you solving my inquiries above. i have one small issues. 
Based on the main question. The 2nd square bracket have slight different data variations where  >>  #Today: I have a pair [sneakers] in [ 2 pair "blue"]

So based on your formula, it captured 2 pair "blue", how should i deal with this issue in order to extract the bluewords if it contains double quotes " " inside the [] bracket.

Comment: @2dayholiday so if you have `#Today: I have a pair [sneakers] in [ 2 pair "blue"]`, you only want to get the `blue`? or you want to include the double quotes and have `"blue"`?

Comment: Yes. I just want to get the blue without the double quotes if it is in between the square bracket []. Otherwise if there is no " " double quotes within the  [ ] square bracket, then just extract as normal ( the 1st formula you showed earlier)

Comment: I have updated answer above @2dayholiday

Comment: i have nothing but grateful. TQ !!